# Python asyncio.sleep SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-asyncio

What am I doing wrong?
When I run this,

```
import asyncio
def oneSecond():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

I get this:

```
File "<string>", line 3
await asyncio.sleep(1)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using Python 3.3

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: Sorry, Python 3.3

Answer (score 7):

You are using the `await` keyword with Python 3.3 but it has not been added to Python before version 3.5.  You should upgrade your Python version.

Also you will have to define your function as `async`:

```
async def oneSecond():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Identical problem on 3.5.1

Comment: I edited the the answer with an additional problem being solved.

Comment: Now when I do await oneSecond() it's a syntax error.

Comment: You have to start it inside asyncio event loop.